# How to display text in a textbox character by character?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a CSS animation type thing and need to display text in a textbox in HTML as if someone is typing it in but no one is actually putting in any text input. I have this so far:

```
<html>
    <head><style>
    input, input:focus {
        border:none;
    }
    input {
        animation: blink-empty 1s infinite;
        border-left: transparent solid 1px;
        margin:5px 
    }
    @keyframes blink-empty {
        50% {border-left: 1px solid #333;}
    }
    </style></head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" value="" id="Box1"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("Box1").focus();
        document.getElementById("Box1").value= ("Text in the textbox");
    };
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My hope is display the "Text in the textbox" value character by character as if a user is typing it in, with some time between each character. So my question is anyone know of a way to do timing and appending lists in js? Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing? What is stopping you from writing this?

Comment: Theres nothing stopping me from setting the value in the text box, it's that i want the text to sort of... Appear character by character as if someone is physically typing it out, and the way i have it now it is automatically there when the page loads.

Comment: Try my suggestion below. You basically just need to create the `addNextLetterToTextBox` function. I don't like spoon-feeding code to people, so give it a shot and see what you can come up with. If you have a more specific question, feel free to follow up. SO doesn't usually respond well to being asked to write code for other people.

Comment: I just re-read it and yes it does look like I am hoping for someone to just give me the solution, but I was looking for more of a direction to go as you have given me. Sorry I am new to js and html. Thanks

Comment: @user3776508 -- Then edit your question and add the *question*. It is perfectly fine to just ask for help with how to proceed -- but we need to know *how* to help you. :) "Teach a man to fish..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) and queue up writing the characters to the textbox.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var box = document.getElementById("Box1"),
        text = "Text in the textbox";

    document.getElementById("Box1").focus();

    for (var i = 0, l = text.length; i < l; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(i) {
            box.value = text.substring(0, i + 1);
        }.bind(this, i), i * 200);
    }
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6338j/)

Comment: Thanks man, i didn't know that text.substring existed(new to js) and it was where the heart of my problems where. Thanks for solving my issue

Comment: @user3776508 no problem! Alternatively you could just append each character like so: http://jsfiddle.net/6338j/1/ (problem with that though, is if someone starts typing their own text in it while it's writing)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the setInterval javascript function to do things on regular time intervals.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

e.g.

```
setInterval(addNextLetterToTextBox, 200);
```

Give it a shot and let us know if you have a more specific question.

Here's a working example:

```
document.getElementById("box1").focus();
setTimeout(addNextLetterToTextBox, 200);
var text = 'hello world';
var i = 0;
function addNextLetterToTextBox(){
    if (i < text.length){
       document.getElementById("box1").value += text[i];
        i+= 1;
       setTimeout(addNextLetterToTextBox, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved my timing issue but how does one append to a text box in html using javascript. I tried using .value but it resets the whole textbox value.

Comment: Thanks this also works for the solution i needed, what i couldn't figure out was how to add text to the previously set value of text. But now I do! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'automagic' way of doing this, you'll just have to brute force it with a setInterval and place the letters in the element one at a time.

Comment: Damn that's what i was scared of and went here for help. :(